# iCal subscribe Holidays fails

Tags: osx-lion, calendar.app

I'm running OS X Lion, using iCal and tried to subscribe to http://ical.mac.com/ical/US32Holidays.ics and it failed saying it couldn't connect. Anybody else get that to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it myself through trial and error. That url still fails but http://ical.me.com/ical/US32Holidays.ics works. I think the iCloud switch-over changed this.